Howe to resolve the React application build error?
We are getting the following error when trying to build our React application using the below build command. Our application is using REACT as web front and middleware C#.net(.net core 3.1).
/ClientApp/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index.d.ts(3340,50):
Type expected.  TS1110
  3338 |         | "transaction-currency"
  3339 |         | "username";
> 3340 |     type OptionalPrefixToken<T extends string> = `${T} ` | "";
       |                                                  ^
  3341 |     type OptionalPostfixToken<T extends string> = ` ${T}` | "";
  3342 |     type AutoFillField = AutoFillNormalField | `${OptionalPrefixToken<AutoFillContactKind>}${AutoFillContactField}`;   
  3343 |     type AutoFillSection = `section-${string}`;

Following is our build command.
dotnet publish "" /p:target=package /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:LastUsedBuildConfiguration=Release /p:LastUsedPlatform="Any CPU"  /p:UsePowerShell=True /p:PackageLocation="%~dp0src\Website<project path>\obj\Release\Package" /p:PackageFileName="%~dp0src\Website<project path>\obj\Release\Package<projectArtifact in zip format>.zip" /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
We are using node version : v12.18.3
Npm Version : 6.14.6
**
We tried deleting node modules folder and tried to upgrade newer version however getting the similar error.
So, please help us to resolve the build error.

Did you try building react alone?

Yes, I did however same issue. I ran npm install and npm run build --prod
